# MongoDB Aggregation: Priorization of matches?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have problems understanding how to sort my items with priorization.

I found that this can be achieved with **aggregate**. Assume this is my Collection:

```
{
'title': 'Applepie'
"categories" : [ 
        "Cake", 
        "Healthy", 
    ],
},
{
'title': 'Chocolatecake'
"categories" : [ 
        "Cake", 
        "Healthy", 
    ],
},
{
'title': 'Some other Cake without apple in the title but in category'
"categories" : [ 
        "Cake", 
        "Apple", 
    ],
}
```

I want to achieve following output if my regex is **apple**:

```
{
    'title': 'Applepie'
    "categories" : [ 
            "Cake", 
            "Healthy", 
        ],
},
{
    'title': 'Some other Cake without apple in the title but in category'
    "categories" : [ 
            "Cake", 
            "Apple", 
        ],
    }
```

This is what I have so far which basically only finds matches until now:

```
var regex = new RegExp('abc', 'i');

db.getCollection('items').aggregate([
    { $match: {
        $or: [
             { title: { $regex: regex }},
             { categories: { $regex: regex }}
        ]
        }
    },
    { 
    /* sort that those with the matching title come first and then those with matching category */
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You *may* be able to achieve that effect to some degree with the `$project` operator that lets you add new fields on the fly that you could then use to sort by, but this would not be very straightforward. See:

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

Mongo doesn't support sorting that would do all that for you.

In practice what is usually done in cases like this is getting the data for both fields matching and sorting/filtering in your own code, or to get two requests - one for the first field matching and one for the second field matching and merging them together. This is not as wasteful as it seems, the performance impact can often be not measurable but you have to test it yourself for your own code, data and usage.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I solved my problem similar to your second suggestion. First query by name, check length of answer, if it does not contain enough items query by category and append those items to the overall response.